# Override -Class Attribute- getter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm defining a Debug class like so:

```
_debug = False

class Debug:
    DrawOutlines = True
    InvinciblePlayer = True
```

I want to override the `Debug` class so that if _debug is False, any class attribute of Debug (that exists) would be False.  What `__`function`__` do I override in order to change how class attributes are accessed?

*Edit:*

I know that simply overriding `__getattribute__` will not work for class attributes:

```
>>> _debug = False
False
>>> class Debug:
...     DrawOutlines = True
...
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...         return _debug and object.__getattribute__(self, name)
...
>>> Debug.DrawOutlines
True
>>> Debug.cake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Debug' has no attribute 'cake'
```

Would this be a case where I would need a metaclass?

Comment: As written, your `__getattribute__` method won't be called, because Debug does not inherit from `object`, i.e. it's an old-style class, and `__getattribute__` is only for new-style classes. However, even with that fixed, your real question remains: the method will be called for attribute lookups on instances of Debug, but not for the class Debug.

Comment: @metamatt Python 3.x classes automatically inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you need a metaclass, because if you define `__getattribute__` in class Debug (which, note, must be a new-style class), Python will invoke that for attribute lookups against instances of Debug, but not for attribute lookups against Debug itself.

That makes sense, because `Debug.__getattribute__` is defined to operate on instances of Debug, not the class Debug. (You could imagine defining a classmethod `__getattribute__`, but I can't find any evidence that Python has any machinery that would invoke such a thing.)

The first thing I thought of here is to add another `__getattribute__` where Python would look for it for Debug class attribute lookups, namely, in the class of which the Debug class is an instance: `Debug.__class__.__getattribute__`.

This does exist and works as you would expect:

```
>>> Debug.__class__.__getattribute__(Debug, 'Draw')
True
>>> Debug.__class__.__getattribute__(Debug, 'Bogus')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __getattribute__
AttributeError: 'DebugType' object has no attribute 'Bogus'
```

But it's not modifiable:

```
>>> Debug.__class__.__getattribute__ = Debug.__getattribute__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'type'
```

This seems to be just a fact of life with the Python implementation; while the concept exists, you're not allowed to modify attributes of builtin types so this approach won't work.

However, metaclasses to the rescue. You probably already know how to do this, but for other readers I'll give an example (and there's another example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820314/how-can-i-override-class-attribute-access-in-python), to which my answer owes some debt).

```
_debug = True
>>> class DebugType(type):
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...             print 'attr lookup for %s' % str(name)
...             return _debug and object.__getattribute__(self, name)
... 
>>> class Debug(object):
...     Draw = True
...     __metaclass__ = DebugType
... 
>>> _debug
False
>>> Debug.Draw
attr lookup for Draw
False
>>> _debug = True
>>> Debug.Draw
attr lookup for Draw
True
```

So to boil it down, the default class implementation for classes is `type`, so the default attribute looker-upper for class attributes is `type.__getattribute__`, and you cannot modify or replace `type.__getattribute__` directly, but you can replace `type` using the metaclass mechanism, and, as in the example above, replace it with a subclass of `type` that has the `__getattribute__` you want.

Answer (score 6):

You override `__getattribute__` to intercept *all* attribute access, or `__getattr__` to get called only for attributes that do not exist:

```
_debug = True
class A(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
       if _debug:
           print attr
       return  object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of it being a class attribute, as it only works on instances.  Would a Metaclass be required here?

Comment: Yes,  if you write a metaclass, and writes the metaclass` `__getattr__` method, it would work for class attributes. It may not work for special dunder methods, though, like `__add__` and `__eq__` as Python's machinnery overrides acess to these special attributes in order to be more efficient

Comment: I just ended up using an object and using a single instance of a class just like this.  However, my original question was for overriding class attributes, not object attributes.  If you edited this answer to either specify that I could use a single object (my example doesn't have `self.*` properties), or provided a meta-class example, I could 'accept' it.