# How can I override class attribute access in python?

Tags: python, attributes

How can I override class attribute access in python?

P.S. Is there a way to leave regular access to class attributes alone but calling a more specific exception on missing attribute?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) magic method is called when the attribute doesn't exist on the instance  / class / parent classes. You'd use it to raise a special exception for a missing attribute:

```
class Foo:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # only called when self.attr doesn't exist
        raise MyCustonException(attr)
```

If you want to customize access to class attributes, you need to define `__getattr__` on the metaclass / type:

```
class BooType(type):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print attr
        return attr

class Boo(metaclass=BooType):
    pass

boo = Boo()
Boo.asd # prints asd
boo.asd # raises an AttributeError like normal
```

If you want to customize *all* attribute access, use the [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) magic method.

Comment: Doesn't that modify instance not class attribute access?

Comment: "If you want to customize all attribute access, use the __getattribute__ magic method." is misleading: to quote a comment from another question:  "__getattribute__ is only invoked on instance attribute access - if you want it invoked on class attribute access, it needs to be on the meta-class."

Comment: As @run_the_race said. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__

Comment: Note: `class Boo(object):` Code does not work with Python3, use `class Boo(metaclass=BooType):
   pass`

Comment: @agf Would you please clarify what you mean by "all attrbiute access" ? (since it does not work for static attributes)

Comment: @run_the_race Can you show an example? It sounds like you're describing the class attribute access scenario, where you need to define it on the type.

Answer (score 2):

[agf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820314/how-can-i-override-class-attribute-access-in-python/9820370#9820370) is correct, and in fact the answer I'm about to give is based on it and owes it some credit.

Just to give more detail on the class-attribute side, which is the part that's actually under question here (as opposed to the difference between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`), I'd like to add a reference to [an answer I wrote to a different similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484634/override-class-attribute-getter/13095408#13095408), which goes into more detail on the difference between class and instance attributes, how this is implemented, and why you need to use a metaclass to influence class attribute lookup.

Comment: Hey, your answer to the other question is nice, but this isn't really an answer to this question. You should either add some content here or post this as a comment on the question or my answer.