# How to override class attribute access in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to override class attribute access in python3. I found this question already [answered for python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820314/how-can-i-override-class-attribute-access-in-python). But the same is not working with Python3. Please help me to understand why this does not work with Python3 and how to get it to work.

Here is the code i am trying to verify in Python3:

```
class BooType(type):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print(attr)
        return attr

class Boo(object):
    __metaclass__ = BooType

boo = Boo()
Boo.asd     #Raises AttributeError in Python3 where as in Python2 this prints 'asd'
```

Comment: [mcve] please. This behaviour should still work on python 3.

Comment: read about descriptors, You can add logic when descriptor is accessed and etc.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , I have added the sample code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html

> Python 3 changes the metaclass hook. It doesn’t disallow the `__metaclass__` field, but it ignores it. Instead, you use a keyword argument in the base-class list:

in your case, you have to change to:

```
class Boo(object, metaclass = BooType):
    pass
```

and that works. This syntax isn't compatible with python 2, though.

There's a way to create compatible code, seen in http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#metaclasses

```
# Python 2 and 3:
from six import with_metaclass
# or
from future.utils import with_metaclass

class Boo(with_metaclass(BooType, object)):
    pass
```