# Differentiate accessing class attribute from within the class (or file) and from outside in python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Let us have an example class Foo in Python:

```
class Foo:
    bar = 'bar'
    def access_bar(self):
        return self.bar
```

Can I, for example print a warning, when accessing `Foo().bar` directly, but at the same time not print this warning when calling `Foo().access_bar()`, which accesses that attribute from within the class?

I tried to implement `__getattribute__` method, but with no luck with differentiating these cases.

I know it's quite a strange question, but please don't answer me like 'You should not need this'.

Comment: `Foo().access_bar()` is not the same as `Foo.access_bar()`

Comment: You appear to have a motivation for asking your question. It could be helpful if you explain why this distinction is necessary (even if it's just curiosity!)

Comment: Do you really want a *class* attribute as opposed to an instance attribute (`self.bar = 'bar'`)? Are you confident you know the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the 'real' answer to your question, which you probably shouldn't do:

```
import inspect


class Foo:
    bar = 'bar'

    def access_bar(self):
        return self.bar

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item == 'bar':
            code = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code
            if not (start_lineno <= code.co_firstlineno <= end_lineno
                    and code.co_filename == __file__):
                print('Warning: accessing bar directly')
        return super().__getattribute__(item)


lines, start_lineno = inspect.getsourcelines(Foo)
end_lineno = start_lineno + len(lines) - 1

print(1, Foo().bar)
print(2, Foo().access_bar())
```

If you do this it's important that there's only one class named `Foo` in the file, otherwise `inspect.getsourcelines(Foo)` may not give the right result.

Comment: `print(Foo.bar)` does not print a warning. This only works on instances of the class `Foo`. You will need a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484634/override-class-attribute-getter) if you want this to work also for class attributes.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! I'll try to play with it. I know there had to be something, because everything can be done in Python! :-)

Comment: good call, I didn't even dare tell the OP to use inspect module for this. "which you probably shouldn't do" gives you my vote :)

Comment: Now it checks if the attribute was called from outside the access_bar() method, what if I wanted to check for outside the Foo class (bar accessed in any method inside the class wouldn't print the warning)?

Comment: How about instead of using `inspect` to find the origin of the call to `__getattribute__`, [modifying it slightly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783680/1362294) so that it learns to print warning? I have no idea how good an idea that is.

Answer (score 2):

you could make `bar` a property which allows to control the access without showing the method call to the outside, and make your attribute private:

```
class Foo:
    __bar = 'bar'
    @property
    def bar(self):
        print("direct access")
        return Foo.__bar
    def access_bar(self):
        return self.__bar

f = Foo()

print("warn",f.bar)
print("OK",f.access_bar())
```

prints:

```
direct access
warn bar
OK bar
```

Comment: I know this way. But I access the ` __bar` a lot from the inside and I didn't like the underscores (and PyCharm warnings about using them). So I try to implement a way that I don't have to use underscores inside the class, but the user get's warned when he tries to access that attribute from the outside.

Comment: @JosefKvita keep in mind that [there are no private class variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes). No matter how much you try to hide the internal variable that holds the value, someone can find a way to access it directly. If this is an attempt to deter other engineers from accessing sensitive fields, maybe try having a conversation with them instead :)

Comment: I know that. I just wanna print a warning, not make it not accessible. :)

Comment: @JosefKvita why are you accessing `__bar` a lot from the inside? Shouldn't the only direct access be from `access_bar`? If not, my answer won't help you, it doesn't differentiate between inside and outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest storing the value in a protected (one leading underscore) or private (two underscores) attribute, and making `bar` a property that can be accessed safely, the equivalent of `access_bar` in your question. That's how this sort of thing is typically done in Python.

```
class Foo:
    _bar = 'bar'

    @property
    def bar(self):
        # do extra things here
        return self._bar
```

A user can still write `foo._bar` or `foo._Foo__bar` (for a private attribute) to get the attribute externally without any warning, but if they are aware of the conventions surrounding leading underscores they will probably feel somewhat uncomfortable doing so and be aware of the risks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another attempt at improving [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54782802/1362294) by adding a metaclass so that it also works for class attributes, and doing away with `inspect` module, and instead add a warning flag to the `__getattribute__` function itself.

```
class FooType(type):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item == "bar":
            print("Warning: accessing bar directly from class")
        return item.__getattribute__(self, item)

class Foo(object, metaclass=FooType):
    bar = 'bar'

    def access_bar(self):
        return self.__getattribute__('bar', warn=False)

    def __getattribute__(self, item, warn=True):
        if item == 'bar' and warn:
            print('Warning: accessing bar directly from instance')
        return super().__getattribute__(item)


print(Foo.bar)
#Warning: accessing bar directly from class
#bar

print(Foo().bar)
#Warning: accessing bar directly from instance
#bar

print(Foo().access_bar())
#bar
```

Comment: The bad thing on this is that I have to access the attribute everywhere inside class (like on 100 places), with a `self.__getattribute__('bar', warn=False)`, not just `self.bar`, or am I wrong? That's surely worse than `self._bar`.

Comment: That's right. I think this solution protects you from using `instance.bar` everywhere, including inside the class. It encourages you to replace `self.bar` with `self.access_bar()`.